# Standarizing the Label to postive intergers in Machine Learning Classification task, why is it recommended?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, machine-learning-model, supervised-learning

When doing a classification task suppose we have 3 targets with notation **-2, -1, 0.**
I read somewhere it is a good practice to Standardize the labels to positive integers.. In this case suppose we change it to **2, 1, 0**. Why is it recommended?

Theoretically I don't think it should matter since each class is unique. But in practice it matters, **why?**

Answer (score 1):

> Please can anybody be kind enough to explain this to me? When doing a
> classification task suppose we have 3 targets with notation -2, -1, 0.
> I read somewhere it is a good practice to Standardize the labels to
> positive integers. In this case suppose we change it to 2, 1, 0. Why
> is it recommended?

Can you please link a reference to this!. Usually in practice you wouldn't use integer labels at all. Instead you would use one-hot encoded labels. Here since you have 3 output classes, the neural network will have 3 output nodes. To be concrete the classes can be represented as follows :

- 0  == >  [1 0 0]
- -1  == >  [0 1 0]
- -2  == >  [0 0 1]

where one out of the three bits is turned ON. This is because in practice the output of the neural network may be a sigmoid (output: range[0,1]) or softmax function (output: probabilities)

Comment: https://keras.io/examples/timeseries/timeseries_classification_from_scratch/  if see in this example they standarized the labels to 0 and 1 from -1 to 1

Answer (score 0):

For machine learning frameworks, it is important that the inputs are within well-specified bounds. Requiring target labels to be positive makes subsequent code and interpretation much easier.

Answer (score 0):

When the integers are positive and start from 0, - they can be used as indices to query some collection, like a list of tensors or a list of strings.